# Why does the class 'ILicenseV2ResultListener' appear in my app after uploading .aab to Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Recently, i got the error when upload my .aab to googleplay console then testing it in internal test mode. Do you know why the class `Lcom/android/vending/licensing/ILicenseV2ResultListener` appeared in my app, although before it not exist in my .aab.
Thank in advance :)

```
06-02 17:49:18.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1327): FATAL EXCEPTION: Binder:1327_4
06-02 17:49:18.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1327): Process: ***, PID: 1327
06-02 17:49:18.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1327): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method enforceNoDataAvail(Landroid/os/Parcel;)V in class Lcom/android/vending/licensing/ILicenseV2ResultListener$Stub; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.android.vending.licensing.ILicenseV2ResultListener$Stub' appears in base.apk!classes2.dex)
06-02 17:49:18.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at com.android.vending.licensing.ILicenseV2ResultListener$Stub.dispatchTransaction(ILicenseV2ResultListener.java:85)
06-02 17:49:18.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at com.google.android.aidl.BaseStub.onTransact(BaseStub.java:78)
06-02 17:49:18.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
06-02 17:49:18.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

i tried to find why it appeared in my code, did gp consle change anything with it